# Apache FOP alternative in pure javascript

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo

I'm looking to transform a xslfo file into pdf in pure JavaScript. Any alternative to FOP Apache (which is in Java...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no XSL FO engines in 100% javascript. There are some that provide Web service interface via REST or SOAP but have a remote formatter like http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf